# Why in UWP application Holding is not called for ListViewItem in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a ListView on a page of my UWP app:

```
        <ListView x:Name="ArrivalsListView" Margin="30,135,40,160">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl Holding="Grid_Holding">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton" Background="Transparent" Text="Edit" Click="EditClick"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="RemoveButton" Background="Transparent" Text="Remove" Click="RemoveClick"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see, it contains MenuFlyout, which is attached to Holding in code behind:

```
    private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);
        flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
    }
```

When I add items to ListView as following

```
    ArrivalsListView.Items.Add(arrival.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

it works fine and Meny Flyout appears in emulator on holding ListView item.

But when I add items as following (I need it for setting color and so on):

```
    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
    listItem.Content = departure.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
    DeparturesListView.Items.Add(listItem);
```

holding does not work (Grid_Holding is not called), and, so that, Menu does not appear.

What is the reason and how can I fix that?

Comment: Your listItem should have it's Holding event.The new ListViewItem not use the DataTemplate

Comment: Well, I tried  `        <ListView x:Name="DeparturesListView" Margin="30,135,40,160">
            <ListViewItem Holding="Grid_Holding" Background="Transparent">
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>` It does not work anyway. So, what exactly should I add to markup?

Comment: ListView ItemSource binding a list.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in the first instance:

```
ArrivalsListView.Items.Add(arrival.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

The `ListView` is given a string as an item. In order for it to display this, it needs to create a `ListViewItem` with that string as its `DataContext`. It inflates the `ItemTemplate` to create the content for the new `ListViewItem`, whereby the `Holding` event is hooked up correctly (since it is part of the template).

In the second instance:

```
ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
listItem.Content = departure.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
DeparturesListView.Items.Add(listItem);
```

you're giving the `ListView` a custom `ListViewItem` that you have configured (with custom colors and so forth, as you mentioned). In this case, the `ListView` just uses the `ListViewItem` as-is. The content of that `ListViewItem` was *not* generated from the `ItemTemplate`. In fact, if you inspect the `ListViewItem` using the Live Visual Tree tools, you'll see that it doesn't contain the `Grid` from the `ItemTemplate`.

Your options are:

- If you're going to make a `ListViewItem` by hand, then you are responsible for setting up any event handlers and such too.
- (My recommendation) Don't create `ListViewItem`s by hand. If you need specialized behaviour or appearance for particular items, then use `ListView.ItemTemplateSelector`, or, if it's just the color of the item that needs to change, bind to the color property (you might need a `IValueConverter` too). This is also better for virtualization, since the `ListView` will be able to recycle items.

Comment: Hi and thanks for detailed reply. The problem with the second option is that I cannot access Items within `ListView` using `foreach` and trying to cust them to `ListViewItem`, although I can see the `ListView.Items` collection in debugger. Is it possible to somehow access items this way?

Comment: Do you really need access to the `ListViewItem` (i.e. the item containers) of each data item, though? There are different ways to populate a `ListView`. I would recommend assigning/binding an `ObservableCollection` to `ListView.ItemsSource` which lets the `ListView` take responsibility for creating each item container, and it keeps the model and view data separate. If you really need to obtain the `ListViewItem` for a particular data item, you can use methods like `ListView.ContainerFromIndex` or `ListView.ContainerFromItem` to do so.